# Prevent popup login form from closing by validation error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, validation, popup

a short version of my problem:
I have a Login form that popups by clicking 'Login'. Then the user can log in by enter email and password. After submitting the form and by success the user get redirecting to his profile.

What I want:
If there is an error in the validation like invalid email oder wrong password, then the login form should not be submitted but display a error message in the login popup instead. So by error the popup window should stay open.

The code:

Popup Login form:

```
<div id="added_login">
    <div class="form_title">
        <h3>Anmelden</h3>
        <img id="form_close" src="images/close.png"/>
    </div>
    <form id="login_form" action="includes/login.inc.php" method="POST">
        <img src="images/or_line.png" />
        <p>Melde dich mit deiner E-Mail Adresse an</p>
        <input id="email" type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-Mail Adresse oder Benutzername">
        <input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Passwort eingeben">
        <div class="error_msg_container"></div>
        <input id="submit" class="button button_highlight" type="submit" name="submit_login" value="Anmelden">
        <div class="login_footer">
            <p class="forget_password">Passwort vergessen?</p>
            <p id="loginform_register" class="button_register">Registrieren</p>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

the jquery/ajax part for the popup form

```
$("#login_form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();
    var submit = $("#submit").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "includes/login.inc.php",
        data: {
            email: email,
            password: password,
            submit_login: submit
        },
        success: function(data){
            $("#error_msg_container").html(data);
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("ERROR");
        }
    })
});
```

the php part for the database:

```
<?php

session_start();

//this function checks the user input
function IsEmail($email){
    if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        //if user input is an email then return true
        return true;
    }else{
        //if user input isnt an email then return false
        return false;
    }
}

if (isset($_POST['submit_login'])) {
    include_once 'db_connect.inc.php';

    $loginid = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);

    if(empty($loginid)){
        //Check for empty email
        echo "<p>E-Mail cannot be empty.</p>";
    }elseif(empty($password)){
        //Check for empty password
        echo "<p>Password cannot be empty.</p>";
    }else{
        $check_email = IsEmail($loginid);
        if($check_email){
            //is input an email
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$loginid'";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        }else{
            //is email a username
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$loginid'";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        }
        $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        //Check for user existing
        if($resultCheck < 1){
            echo "<p>No such a user found.</p>";
        }else{
            if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                //Dehashing password
                $hashedPasswordCheck = password_verify($password, $row['password']);
                //Check for correct password
                if($hashedPasswordCheck == false){
                    header("Location: ../index.php?login=wrong_password");
                    exit();
                }elseif($hashedPasswordCheck == true){

                    if($row[active] == 0){
                        echo "<p>Your accent have to set on active</p>";
                    }else{
                        //Log in the user
                        $_SESSION[user_id] = $row[id];
                        $_SESSION[user_firstname] = $row[firstname];
                        $_SESSION[user_lastname] = $row[lastname];
                        $_SESSION[user_gender] = $row[gender];
                        $_SESSION[user_username] = $row[username];
                        $_SESSION[user_email] = $row[email];
                        $_SESSION[user_level] = $row[level];
                        $_SESSION[user_points] = $row[points];
                        $_SESSION[loggedIn] = true;

                        header("Location: ../index.php?login=success");
                        exit();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}else{
    header("Location: ../index.php");
    exit();
}
```

The problem now is that nothing happen.. the popup login window stay open but the error message doesn't show up and even if the input are correct nothing happen..

Hope you guys can help me. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
There is issue in your jquery code.
```

In ajax success function,you have mentioned div id 'error_msg_container' which is actually a class in html.
Code should be

```
    success: function(data){
        $(".error_msg_container").html(data);
    }
```

Comment: Wow.. just one letter!! Thank you very much. Changed it now. But how to redirect to profile page if inputs were successful?

Comment: you can check for success response from ajax,and redirect accordingly.Means when you got the desired response in ajax,then in ajax success function write a code for url redirection.

Comment: you mean like `success: function(data){ if(data == "success"){ //redirect }else{$(".error_msg_container").html(data);}` ?

Comment: Yes . Check the condition for success and then redirect .

Comment: Got it! Thank you sir! Unfortunately I cannot vote up. But you saved my ass.